# handle click event custom server control

Tags: asp.net, postback, custom-server-controls, buttonclick

I have control with imagebutton:

```
    ... 
    ImageButton btn;

    public MyControl()
    {
        btn = new ImageButton();      
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(this);
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        btn.Height = Height;
        btn.Width = Height;

        btn.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(RaiseLeftClickEvent);
    }

    private void RaiseLeftClickEvent(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

When I clicked the button Click event not fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must create click event in OnInit scope..

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(this);
    base.CreateChildControls();
    btn.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(RaiseLeftClickEvent);
}
```

**UPDATE**:

First, base class of the control must be WebControl class.

And also OnInit scope define button's event:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
    Controls.Clear();

    base.CreateChildControls();
    btn.Click += btnImageButton_Click;
    Controls.Add(btn);

}


void btnImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Handle Click event.. 
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I think there is an issue about RaiseLeftClickEvent parameter. Are you sure the definition of RaiseLeftClickEvent is right?

Comment: this method was autogenerated.

Comment: I think wrong thing is overriding CreateChildControls and also i think the control must be added to Control collection in Init scope.. Hope this helps..